# Read multiple gmail inbox in python

Tags: python, list, gmail

I have a script that can read gmail inbox but only for a particular account. So, what i trying to achieve is to have a list to store multiple credentials and login to read inbox for multiple accounts.

My script:

```
#email inbox declaration (receiver)
EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "xxx@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "xxx"

#email
#Main function
class SendMail(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id_manager):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_manager = int(id_manager)

    def run(self):

        while True:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
            mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
            mail.list()
            mail.select('inbox')
            result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")  # (ALL/UNSEEN)
            i = len(data[0].split())
            for x in range(i):
                latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
                result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
                # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
                # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
                raw_email = email_data[0][1]
                raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
                email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

                # Header Details
                date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
                if date_tuple:
                    local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
                    local_message_date = "%s" % (str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
                    email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
                    email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
                    global subject
                    subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

                # Body details
                for part in email_message.walk():

                    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                        print("From:", email_from)

                        print("Email To:", email_to)
                        print("date:", local_message_date)
                        print("Subject:", subject)
                        print("body:", body.decode('utf-8'))

                        #condition
                    else:
                        continue


def mainSendEmail():
    thread_id = ("0")
    led_index = 0
    thread_list = list()
    for objs in thread_id:
        thread = SendMail(led_index)
        thread_list.append(thread)
        led_index += 1
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainSendEmail()
```

My list that store multiple credentials. listA is email and listB is the password. The listA's email and listB password is corelatted. For example, listA first email is listB's first password

```
listA = [('xxx@yahoo.com',), ('asd@gmail.com',), ('test@gmail.com',)]
listB = [('passwordxxx',), ('passwordForasd',), ('passwordFortest',)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two lists with `zip()` function to create a list of tuples. Each element in this new list contains a username and its password. Then you can iterate on this list to check all emails. Add these lines to the top of your `run` function:

```
def run(self):
    listA = [('xxx@yahoo.com',), ('asd@gmail.com',), ('test@gmail.com',)]
    listB = [('passwordxxx',), ('passwordForasd',), ('passwordFortest',)]
    for each_credential_info in tuple(zip(listA, listB)):
        while True:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
            mail.login(each_credential_info[0][0], each_credential_info[1][0])
            mail.list()
            ...
```

However, I'm wondering why you use tuples in `listA` and `listB`. You could use simple lists and write a simpler code:

```
def run(self):
    listA = ['xxx@yahoo.com', 'asd@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com']
    listB = ['passwordxxx', 'passwordForasd', 'passwordFortest']
    for each_credential_info in tuple(zip(listA, listB)):
        while True:
            mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
            mail.login(each_credential_info[0], each_credential_info[1])
            mail.list()
            ...
```

And I have some more suggestions for your code to have better performance and ....

When you don't have a break in your infinite loop `while True`, you won't have iteration on the new loop `for each_credential_info in tuple(zip(listA, listB))`. In this case, you need to merge these two loops:

```
def run(self):
    listA = ['xxx@yahoo.com', 'asd@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com']
    listB = ['passwordxxx', 'passwordForasd', 'passwordFortest']
    credential_info = tuple(zip(listA, listB))
    credential_info_index = -1
    while True:
        credential_info_index = (credential_info_index + 1) % len(credential_info)
        print("Processing email: " + credential_info[credential_info_index][0] + ", " + credential_info[credential_info_index][1])
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        mail.login(credential_info[credential_info_index][0], credential_info[credential_info_index][1])
        mail.list()
        ...
```

Or simply make and use a circular itterator:

```
from itertools import cycle
def run(self):
    listA = ['xxx@yahoo.com', 'asd@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com']
    listB = ['passwordxxx', 'passwordForasd', 'passwordFortest']
    credential_info = cycle(tuple(zip(listA, listB)))
    while True:
        print("Processing email: " + next(credential_info)[0] + ", " + next(credential_info)[1])
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        mail.login(next(credential_info)[0], next(credential_info)[1])
        mail.list()
        ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur respond, i try with ur code but it seem it only able to read the first account but not the second and third.

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH You are welcome. Are you sure?!!! It's not possible. I have tested the code for creating the list and it's not possible that you iterate on a list, but the action performs on just the first element. Add `print("Processing email: " + each_credential_info[0] + ", " + each_credential_info[1])` after the `while True:` (as the first loop instruction) and let me know the result.

Comment: As u said I print the `processing email` and its just showing 1 credentials instead of 2. It showed `Processing email: xxx@yahoo.com, passwordxxx`

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH Check the edited answer.